# Invalid Type Text Keeps Printing

Tags: java, repeat

I'm making a number guessing game in java. I want the application to print a line when the user types a string instead of an integer. This is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class guessing_game {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random generator = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        number = generator.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("Guess the number!");
        game(number);
    }
    public static void game(int number) {
        int inputStorage = 0;
        boolean b = true;
        while (b) {
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                inputStorage = input.nextInt();
                if (inputStorage == number) {
                    System.out.println("You've won!");
                    b = false;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong number! Try again.");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Only numbers! Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the user types a string, like a letter, the application shows: Only Numbers! Try again. The application doesn't stop printing this line over and over again. How to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert something that is not a number then `(input.hasNextInt())` will return false, hence you won´t go into that if-statement and go the lowest else statement.

I would suggest you read the next string instead, and if the string is not convertable to an int then you handle that case

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. I made a new string and set that string to whatever the user has typed. Then I used this line: `int inputStorage1 = Integer.parseInt(inputString);`. Then by using catch / try and if statements I got it to work. Can you explain to me why it only shows "only numbers" once when I do it this way? Because my application won't stop printing the line when I just use an integer. My new application: http://pastebin.com/8m4WsV0T

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void game(int number) {
    while (true) {
        try{
            System.out.print("Guess a number: "); // prompt user to enter an int
            inputStorage = input.nextInt(); // read the number
            if (inputStorage == number) {
                System.out.println("You've won!");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Wrong number! Try again.");
            }
        } catch(final Exception ignored) { // input was not a number
            System.out.println("\nOnly numbers! Try again.");
            input.next(); // consume the invalid input
        }
    }
}
```

This will prompt the user to enter a number and only tell the user that they need to enter a number if one wasn't presented.

If the user doesn't enter a valid number, an exception will be thrown and caught in the `catch` statement. In this case, the entered input was not an integer.

Comment: My problem is that my application won't stop printing "Only numbers! Try again."

Comment: Yes, but every millisecond there will come a new line saying Only numbers! I already made it work. I turned the input into a string and then parsed it to an integer. If that's not possible, a catch / try statement will say Only numbers. But I have no idea why that message comes only once.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch statement it is simple

```
try {
   ...
} catch (NumberFormatException, ScannerException exception) {
   System.out.println("Input must be a number.");
}
```